# What is the best way to create simple filter functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

Many times I face the same problem: I want to filter an array with a simple condition e.g. check for non/equality, greater than, less than, contains...

My code looks like this:

```
var result = [1, 2, 3, 4].filter(function(i) {
   return i > 2; 
});
console.log(result); // [3, 4]
```

It would by nice to have shortcuts to such a simple operations so
I created some helper functions:

```
function isGreaterThan(value) {
    return function(original) {
        return value < original;
    }
}
[1, 2, 3, 4].filter(isGreaterThan(2)); // [3, 4]
```

or:

```
function isGreaterThan(value, original) {
    return value < original;
}
[1, 2, 3, 4].filter(isGreaterThan.bind(null, 2)); // [3, 4]
```

Is there a better way how to do this in javascript? Does javascript have any built-in functions to support these simple comparisions?

Comment: I don't think there is a better way.

Comment: Are you asking about performance or clean code? (I think that your way is the best in clean code but in performance the traditional for loop could be better).

Comment: The question is about clean code

Comment: Ask on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If ==, <, >, ! were functions problem would be solved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Madox, what you've stumbled upon is the concept of [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)! And you'll be glad to hear that there is an [entire JavaScript community](https://gitter.im/ramda/ramda) built around that idea. With [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/0.18.0/index.html) your code would look like:

```
var filterSmallNumbers = filter(gte(3));
var smallNumbers = filterSmallNumbers([1,2,3,4,5,6]);
```

And [it works](http://goo.gl/XFpjbY).

All Ramda provides, is a list of "curried helper functions" like the one you showed. If you'd rather curry your own helper functions, then you might want a `curry` helper function which reduces the boilerplate: `var isGreaterThan = curry(function(a, b){ return a > b })`. This curry function is provided by most utility libraries like Underscore, Lodash or Ramda.

Comment: Thanks, I was exactly looking for helper functions like gte, eq, has, ... from the Ramda. But I am still not sure If I want to learn and use other library since ES6 has a lot of it's features.

Comment: @madox2 once you start digging into the [Rambda source code](https://github.com/ramda/ramda) you'll start finding skeletons immediately.

Answer (score 3):

I'll expand on @Avaq's answer a little bit here. You don't need a lib like Rambda to start using currying. You can start doing this with ES6 today.

It seems you already understand the concept here. This is already a curried function. (Each sequenced function takes only one argument)

```
function isGreaterThan(value) {
    return function(original) {
        return value < original;
    }
}
```

With ES6 [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), this gets a lot easier.

```
const gt = x => y => y > x;
```

Notice how you flipped the the operator `>` to a `<` in your function to make the usage seem more natural? It's very common with curried functions to first take the operand that is least likely to change. With `gt`, I think it's better to use `>` here since that's the name of our function, but instead flip the operands. That's why you see me returning `y > x` instead of `x > y`. `gt(5)` returns a function `y => y > 5`, which feels very natural to me.

Without further ado, let's see it work in a `filter`

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6].filter(gt(3)); //=> [4,5,6]
```

If you need this to work in an ES5 environment, you can transpile it with [babel](http://babeljs.io/) very easily. The result should look very familiar

```
"use strict";
var gt = function gt(x) {
    return function (y) {
        return y > x;
    };
};
```

---

And with that, you're at the doorstep of functional programming. There's a ton of fun stuff to learn. With the kind of problem we discussed here, I think you'd be interested in learning about [function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) next.

Here's a basic composition to whet your appetite

```
// filter out odd numbers
const mod = x => y => y % x;
const eq = x => y => y === x;
const comp = f => g => x => f(g(x));
const isEven = comp (eq (0)) (mod (2));
[1,2,3,4,5,6].filter(isEven); //=> [2,4,6]
```

Comment: I am already familiar with ES6 and it's cool. Anyway, thanks for the tips!

Answer (score -4):

you were almost there, here is the correct one:

```
var original = 2;
function isGreaterThan(value) {
    return value > original;
}
var result = [1, 2, 3, 4].filter(isGreaterThan);
// result is [3, 4]
```

[reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Example_Filtering_out_all_small_values)